# WebHook: How to POST form data to a URL?

Tags: solspace-freeform, forms, hook

I'm using an external service - Unbounce.com - to manage my landing pages. Unbounce gives me the option to post to an external URL using their Webhook Integration.

I'm using Freeform to manage my forms. Can anyone give me some advice on how to hook this up? I suspect it's going to be a URL with "ACT" in it, but I'm not really sure where to start? Do I create a receiver form in Freeform?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use Freeform, you'll need to write an [extension](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/extensions.html) to take the form data sent to Freeform and send a copy elsewhere. The hook you want to use is probably [freeform_module_insert_end](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/extension_hooks/#freeform_module_insert_end), as this will have validated the form data and only includes what is valid for the form (not all post data). This means the data is saved in Freeform (with Freeform handling all the validation and heavy lifting), then sent via your extension to Unbounce.